# Generic function definition as type in F# signature file

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I can define a generic signature type and define a function which implements that signature:

```
[<Measure>] type ms
type timer<'a,'b> = ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b * int64<ms>;;
let timeit:timer<'a,'b> = fun f x -> ((f x), 1L<ms>);;
```

I can also put that type definition in an F# signature file (.fsi).

```
module Utils =
    type timer<'a,'b> = ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b * int64<ms>
```

But when I try to use that type definition in the implementation file, the compiler says 'The type "timer" is not defined'.

```
[<Measure>] type ms

module Utils =
    let timeit:timer<'a,'b> = fun f x -> ((f x), 1L<ms>);;
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: If you are coming from a C background, signature files look very similar to header files.  They are actually not, signature files are actually significantly less powerful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare your `timer<_, _>` type in the `.fs` file too.

Basically, the signature file is a convenience to document the public API of the source file, but it doesn't by itself declare anything that can be used in the source file. If this is not something you need, you can just drop the signature file and only use a source file.